# What's the difference between a static struct method and a static class method?

Tags: c#, methods, static

I recently discovered that structs in C# can have methods.

Quite accidentally, I found myself to have been using the static method of an empty struct in my code, rather than the static method of a static class that I thought I was working with!

e.g.

```
public struct Foo
{
    public static void Bar(Param param)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

It's not really being used as a struct at this point, as it has no properties at all!

Is this very different from using a static method of a class (static or otherwise)? Are there any reasons to prefer one over the other? (My gut tells me that using the static struct method is, at minimum, less intuitive)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No, static members belong to the *type* and not to *instances of the type*.  There is no difference (neither with respect to performance nor semantics) between declaring static class members and static struct members.

It is important to note that if a type's only function is to contain static members, you should use a static class instead.  With structs, there is an implicit and unchangeable public, no-argument constructor.  If the type will not have any instance methods, the ability to create instances should be removed.  Declaring a class `static` is the same as declaring it `abstract sealed`, so developers will not be able to accidentally create instances that have no purpose.

Comment: Declaring a class `static` has the added benefit (over `abstract sealed`) of allowing the compiler to flag any usages of the type in variable declarations or casts as errors.

Comment: @mikez That too, as well as flagging any instance member declarations as errors.

Comment: @mikez I think a more important distinction is that `abstract sealed class` is simply invalid C#.

Comment: @svick Of course, my point was that one shouldn't think of `static class` as "the same as" `abstract sealed class`. A static class has the additional restrictions compared to those conferred by abstract and sealed.

Comment: There is this funny thing about a `struct` with no non-static data that your instance is already assigned before you use that "implicit" no-argument instance constructor. For example the following is OK: `static void Example() { Foo local; var okStr = local.ToString(); var okBool = local.Equals(local); }` Here `Foo` is a struct like in the question. The funny thing is that `local` looks unassigned, but since there are no instance fields, every field is (vacuously) assigned, so this is not a use of unassigned variable. The C# compiler is happy, and it runs.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior is no different. C# bastardized structs by hugely increasing the intersection of struct and class features. Personally I would just use a class because it seems more correct to me (certainly more in line with the conventions in most languages).

Comment: One could define methods and constructors for structures in C++ already, so it is not a brand new feature that was first introduced in C#.

Comment: What about a struct which has `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]` set? That couldn't be replaced by a class.