# Linq static method in SELECT statement

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, linq-to-objects

I'm working with EF and have some queries. Here is my code

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = from c in context.Customers 
    select new Customer
    {
        ID = c.ID,
        Name = c.Name,
        LastName = c.LastName,
        DepID = c.DepID,
        Editable = SomeStruct.Check(c.DepID)
    }

public struct SomeStruct
{
    public static bool Check(int depID)
    {
        //Here I have some logic
    }
}
```

It works fine.
However, if I declare `SomeStruct` as `class` it will fail.

My questions are:

1. Why does it happens ?
2. Does using of static function forces the query to execute ?

Comment: can I confirm: if `SomeStruct` is a `class`, but the method is still `static`, then it *doesn't* work - am I understanding it correctly? If so: what happens? What is the exception?

Comment: Are you really sure that your code is working when SomeStruct is a struct? Can you please add ToList() to your select statement and see if everything is still working?

Answer (score 6):

In your code method `SomeStruct.Check(c.DepID)` should be transformed to SQL query. This describes behaviour with class/structs and so on. It is due to different work of Entity Framework with such methods in class and structure. But you can do this check on client:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = from c in context.Customers 
    select new
    {
        ID = c.ID,
        Name = c.Name,
        LastName = c.LastName,
        DepID = c.DepID
    }
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Select(d => new Customer
    {
        ID = c.ID,
        Name = c.Name,
        LastName = c.LastName,
        DepID = c.DepID,
        Editable = SomeStruct.Check(c.DepID)
    });
```

Or you can set `Editable` property as readonly property:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Guid DepID { get; set; }
    public bool Editable { get { return SomeStruct.Check(DepID); } }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easily reproducible that your code can not work with linq to entities. *Anything* that can not be translated into sql will throw a runtime exception. In you case:

> NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Check(Int32)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

If you got it running at some point, that can not have been related to `struct` or `class` differences, see [What's the difference between a static struct method and a static class method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372194/whats-the-difference-between-a-static-struct-method-and-a-static-class-method)

You probably changed something else at the same time, like adding `ToList()` before the `select`.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing it's a runtime issue, in many cases you are describing, this is a reference issue. EF's linq provider supports calling a static method declared in a class (static or not).

1. I recommend that you to change your struct to a class AND make it static to help you investigate the issue.
2. No, nothing will be executed before you calling a first iteration or customers.

Hope this helps